# Get-WinEvent returning a string?

Tags: powershell

anyway to get an array of strings from a Get-WinEvent? what i currently have is

```
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName bcdc01 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} |
Select-Object -Property timecreated,
@{Name='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}}
```

is there anyway to return this as an array of strings or something similar?

Comment: How about `.... | %{out-String}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Foreach-Object` and string formating:

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName bcdc01 -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4771;data=$Localusername} | Foreach-Object {
  '{0}: {1}' -f $_.timecreated,$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]
}
```

(Note: I haven't been able to test your property extraction).